# How to use combiner in aggregateMessages in GraphX

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

In GraphX aggregateMessages API

```
class Graph[VD, ED] {
  def aggregateMessages[Msg: ClassTag](
      sendMsg: EdgeContext[VD, ED, Msg] => Unit,
      mergeMsg: (Msg, Msg) => Msg,
      tripletFields: TripletFields = TripletFields.All)
    : VertexRDD[Msg]
}
```

However I want to modify the return type of merge stage which means I want something like `combineByKey` instead of `reduceByKey`, how can I do it based on the advantage of GraphX? Or in other words, how can I just use the result of `sendMsg` and skip the `mergeMsg` stage of this function?

The advantage of GraphX I mean is "vertex centric", if I use `map` and `combineByKey` function it will do global shuffling, which cost plenty of time, going against the idea "vertex centric"

Comment: I have found a possible solution but it is not very general. By the way, if you have a better choice of graph compute engine integrating with Neo4j, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: I have put it in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

the `collectEdges` in `GraphOps` API might help.

It collects the neighbor edges of each vertex and can return a `VertexRDD[Array[Edge[ED]]]` type, which means it changes the return type and collect the messages simultaneously, see [API documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphOps)